# Git fatal error on OpenShift clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, openshift

When trying to clone my Rails application via Git, I am geting:

> Cloning into ruby... ssh: Could not resolve hostname
>   ruby-xxxxxxxxx.rhcloud.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not
>   known fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

For this, I am running the following command:

```
$ git clone ssh://5311f57b5973ca7b7b00012b@ruby-xxxxxxxxx.rhcloud.com/~/git/ruby.git/
```

I can access the app from the web console & have installed the rhc gem & the set up was successful.

Anybody know what I can do to try to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure that your ssh url is correct. You can run `rhc apps` to get a list all your applications and their assets.